# Как применить в React код написанный на нативном js (создать похожую реализацию)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, swiper

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Ребята, приветствую.  Заклинило на одном моменте.  В react-компоненте внутри componentDidMount вызывается слайдер . Необходимо создать дополнительную обертку node, внутри которой будет вызываться методы слайдера.  Нужно в каждый экземпляр слайдера передавать разные дом-элементы. Есть похожий пример на js, но не могу понять как его можно применить для react.  Занимаюсь сейчас поддержкой существующего кода и не хочется переписывать все заново ) . Буду благодарен за помощь или дельный совет .[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Приведите код в текстовом виде

Comment: вам нужно в componentDidMount получить некий дом-элемент, правильно? В этом суть вопроса? Если да, то по какой логике будет избираться этот элемент и существует ли он в исходной верстке этого компонента/дочерних/родительских?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-moser-c5ten?file=/src/Slider.module.css пример слайдера на React.js

Comment: по идее мне нужно создать дополнительную обертку вокруг слайдера . и обратиться к ней для поиска дочерних элементов. я так для себя понимаю задачу )

Comment: https://swiperjs.com/react/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Обёртка для слайдера и прочие не создаваемые автоматически элементы, вроде кнопок, должны быть предусмотрены в вёрстке вашего компонента изначально. Чтобы корректно получить к ним доступ, используйте [рефы](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html). Будет как-то так:

```
...
constructor(props) {
    ...
    this.dom_slider = React.createRef();
    this.dom_slider_prevButton = React.createRef();
    this.dom_slider_nextButton = React.createRef();
}
...
componentDidMount() {
    this.slider = new Swiper(this.dom_slider.current, {
        ...
        navigation: {
            prevEl: this.dom_slider_prevButton.current;
            nextEl: this.dom_slider_nextButton.current;
        }
    })
}

render() {
    return (
        ...
        <div class='slider'>
            <div ref={this.dom_slider} class='slider__container' />
            <div ref={this.dom_slider_prevButton} class='slider__prevButton' />
            <div ref={this.dom_slider_nextButton} class='slider__nextButton' />
        </div>
        ...
    );
}
```

Comment: спасибо за подсказку. сложная для меня тема еще. подскажите при использовании рефов где будут определяться метода самого swiper - внутри componentDidMount() {
    this.slider(this.dom_slider.current, {
        ...
        navigation: {
            prevEl: this.dom_slider_prevButton,
            nextEl: this.dom_slider_nextButton,
        }
    })
}
не совсем сейчас понятно

Comment: Прошу прощения, я опечатался. Сейчас должно стать все ясно)